# User defined functions for string match function

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns say STREET and STREETNAME. I want to make a function that matches the common part of both strings and returns the common part.

example from my two row table

```
STREET          STREETNAME
-----------     -----------------
ORANGE          ORANGE BLOSSOM
MAIN 324-A      MAIN STREET
```

So my function `print dbo.strMatch([STREET],[STREETNAME])`

Output:

```
ORANGE
MAIN
```

and then update another column called sample with the output.

1. Is it possible to pass columns as parameters like this
2. If this is legal, how do you loop through the rows and compare the entries?

I am a c++ programmer and I could easily make this function in C++ but I am required to do this in SQL which I am new to and my book does not teach me any capabilities of SQL doing this.

in C++ these two columns would be passed as array or linked lists or the like.
the on the i-th iteration I would compare entries of row i in both columns.
Then I would loop through both strings using j=0,1,2,..n  where I check the 1st char of both string on j=0, 2nd char on j=1 until the match fails and store the correct matches concatenated into a string and return that string and update the third array.

Since I am dealing with tables and not necessarily arrays in the same sense I do not have the slightest clue how to go about this the most efficient way.
Can someone please help me.

Thanks